# Interacting with a GCP VM instance through site address

Tags: elasticsearch, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, bitnami

I’m having trouble trying to access and manage a virtual machine instance in GCP.

Basically, two years ago or so I created a project that required elasticsearch. I implemented this module through google cloud platform by using: “Elasticsearch Certified by Bitnami”.

By accessing the site address, and with the credentials provided by GCP I was able to do everything I needed by the use of plugins with the site address directly (Using POST, PUT, and GET commands with the link http://35.xxx.xx.xxx//elasticsearch/...).

This worked perfectly, however, I discontinued the function on the site for a while, and now that I need to use it again, following the same steps doesn’t work, as GCP no longer provides a site address to access or interact with the VM as I did before.

I thought this had to do directly with Bitnami, however a similar question on their support site
answered by one of their engineers seems to point to google as the source of this change: https://community.bitnami.com/t/no-more-site-address-gcp-wordpress/52133 (in my case is an elasticsearch instance rather than a wordpress one).

Reserving a static ip and inserting it into the previous link format didn’t work either. (http://external-IP//elasticsearch/...)

So my question is: is there now a way in which I can still interact with the VM as it was previously possible? If so, how can I do this, and what address should I use? And if it is not possible, how can I interact with the VM instance to assign a mapping and send queries directly?

(If necessary, I found someone that did a similar implementation to what I did before so you can get an idea of what I’m looking for: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wv2EoMQ-5vQ)

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What do you have now at the end of the deployment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be serveral reasons why you can't access your Elasticsearch instance.

1. Verify if the Elasticsearch is running with `sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh status`
2. [GCP Firewall](https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/firewalls/list) settings - by default API works on 9200 so make sure it's open (your port may be different but I used default one in this example):

```
$ gcloud compute firewall-rules list | grep 9200
elasticsearch                       default  INGRESS    1000      tcp:22,tcp:9200,tcp:9300,tcp:9600        False
```

3. VM's firewall settings - check `sudo iptables -L` and verify if there are no rule blocking elasticsearch port.

Also if your Elasticsearch was updated lately configuration may have changed (but it's a guess at this point) and may be the cause.

But - if everything's OK with your instance you should be able to access it just by typing `http://my_vm_external_ip:9200` and you should get an API resposne:

```
  "name" : "elasticsearch-1-vm",
  "cluster_name" : "bnCluster",
  "cluster_uuid" : "0q4a-ouNQ0OechAIXz1S0g",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.8.0",
    "build_flavor" : "oss",
    "build_type" : "tar",
    "build_hash" : "757314695644ea9a1dc2fecd26d1a43856725e65",
    "build_date" : "2020-06-14T19:35:50.234439Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.5.1",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

To be sure this is a viable solution I just deployed ["Elasticsearch by Bitnami" from marketplace.](https://pantheon.corp.google.com/marketplace/details/bitnami-launchpad/elasticsearch) Then I created a firewall rule:

`gcloud compute --project=my_project firewall-rules create elasticsearch --direction=INGRESS --priority=1000 --network=default --action=ALLOW --rules=tcp:22,tcp:9200,tcp:9300,tcp:9600 --source-ranges=0.0.0.0/0 --target-tags=elasticsearch-1-deployment`

I used `--target-tags=elasticsearch-1-deployment` tag that deployment has created for the VM running Elasticsearch - you may use different tags or not tags at all - it's just an example.

This documentation may also be helpful for you https://docs.bitnami.com/google/faq/administration/use-firewall/